# Downsampling a binary file

Tags: filters, sampling, downsampling, resampling, gps

[TEXBAT](https://radionavlab.ae.utexas.edu/texbat/) is a recorded dataset about spoofing scenarios for evaluating GPS signal authentication techniques.

On this project, there are recorded GPS signals stored as complex 16- bit samples at a rate of 25 Msps.

I want to change its sample rate because maximum sample rate of my SDR ([RTL-SDR](https://www.rtl-sdr.com/)) is 3.2Msps.

How can I change its sample rate from 25Msps to sample rates below than 3.2Msps?

Comment: it would be useful to mention that this is cross-posted from https://www.reddit.com/r/DSP/comments/wzbgl1/resampling_a_binary_file/, because people answering here could then see what suggestions were already made on the reddit site...

Comment: With a resampler, or especially, just using decimation.  Really, as @fearless_fool indicated, it would be nice if you could not only link to the previous discussion, but also worked with what you've learned there. For example, the first comment you got there was to research `doc resample` in matlab, and that's not very … instructively phrased, but it's spot on. You need to research resampling – you already know that now, so I guess you did that in the two hours between that comment and posting the question here. What has that research yielded? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I need to sample I and Q components separately of the complex sampled signal.

Comment: that statement makes no sense. your complex sampled signal is already I and Q, separably. It's literally how complex signals are respresented in computers.

Comment: Does not this process make sense? STEP 1: I will get I and Q from the file. STEP 2: I will resample I component and store it to a file STEP 3: I will resample Q component and store it to a file STEP 4: New signal will be I+j*Q

Comment: I believe what @MarcusMüller was saying is that you don't need to leave the complex (IQ) domain in order to do resampling.

Comment: @fearless_fool exactly. Because decimation resampling filters are symmetrical and hence real, there's no difference in treating the complex signal with a resampler or treating the complex signal as two real signals and resampling them individually. If there **was** a difference, you would have to treat the complex signal as one complex signal, not as two real signals. So, the requirement to divide I and Q into two files and treat them separately makes no sense – albeit an easy step, it doesn't solve any problem. If there was something that needed to be solved, treating I and Q separately would

Comment: *break* the signal. Luckily, there's nothing to solve here. Just resample!